# Convergence of a series involving Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering how to show whether this series converges or not:

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\frac{\pi^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)!}\zeta(-2m-1)$

Numerically it converges after a few terms in wolfra alpha. But what test can one  actually use to show that it converges?

thanks

Comment: the zeta values at negative integers are given  by $-B_n/(n+1)$ where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers. The asymptotics of this numbers can be given straightforwardly by stirlings approximation. Can u take it from here?

Comment: I guess I will have to use the ratio test from there onwards, right?

Comment: i would suppose, yes

Comment: Is this reasoning correct? If $(-1)^{n+1} B_n \approx \frac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^2n}$ then  $(-1)^{2n+1} B_{2n+1} \approx \frac{2(2n+1)!}{(2\pi)^{2n+1}}$

Comment: $S=\ln\dfrac2\pi$

Comment: HI Lucian, where did you get that series from?

Comment: @onephys: Just integrate $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_{2n}~\dfrac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}~=~x\coth x,~$ after first dividing both sides by *x*, using the aforementioned identity $~\zeta(1-n)=-\dfrac{B_n}n~$ for $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is my working. I hope it is correct:
The series is given by:
$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\frac{\pi^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)!}\zeta(-2m-1)$

Therefore the coefficients are:
$c_m=(-1)^{m}\frac{\pi^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)!}\zeta(-2m-1)$

and
$c_{m-1}=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{\pi^{2m}}{(2m)!}\zeta(-2m+1)$

Applying the ratio test we can leave out the term $-1$:

$$\left|\frac{c_m}{c_{m-1}}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{\pi^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)!}\zeta(-2m-1)}{\frac{\pi^{2m}}{(2m)!}\zeta(-2m+1)}\right|=\left|\frac{\pi^{2m+2}\zeta(-2m-1)(2m)!}{\pi^{2m}\zeta(-2m+1)(2m+2)!}\right|=\left|\frac{\pi^{2}\zeta(-2m-1)}{\zeta(-2m+1)(2m+2)(2m+1)}\right|$$
Now using the approximation of the Riemann Zeta function with Bernoulli numbers we get:
$$=\left|\frac{\pi^{2}\frac{B_{2m+1}}{2m+2}}{\frac{B_{2m-1}}{2m}(2m+2)(2m+1)}\right|=\left|\frac{\pi^{2}B_{2m+1}2m}{B_{2m-1}(2m+2)^2(2m+1)}\right|$$
Not sure how to proceed from here.